# Calling viewWillTransitionToSize: manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I currently have a UiViewController called `Page2`
Now if the orientation of the Iphone is changed to landscape the following method is called which is well and good

```
    -(void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator 
    {
         /*The orientation of the phone just changed*/
    }
```

Now My issue is that if the user is already in landscape mode in ViewController page1 and goes to UIViewController `Page2` the above method is not called. I know I can check the current orientation of the phone using the following code

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        //Its in landscape mode
    }
```

However I do not know what parameters to pass for size to the method (that gets called automatically only when the orientation changes) I would like to call this method manually if I detect its in landscape mode. Any suggestions on how to obtain the current size to pass to the method below in which the width would be greater than the height (since its in landscape mode)

```
 -(void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator ;
```

I tried doing this

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [self viewWillTransitionToSize:self.view.frame.size withTransitionCoordinator:nil];
    }
```

However the height was greater than the width indicating it was still in portrait mode ...  What am i doing wrong ? How can I call this method manually and pass the current size in which width is greater than the height ?

**Update:**

I would like to give a little more background. I currently have two UIViewControllers `PageOne` and `PageTwo`. Now `PageTwo` has something like this in it for orientation control. The control flow goes from `PageOne` to `PageTwo`

```
//When device rotates
-(void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{

    DKTuner* sensitivityTuner;
    if (size.width > size.height)
    {   //Yes this is the landscape mode - Realign some controls to a different position.
        .....        
    }
    else
    {
        // this is portrait mode
        .....
    } 
}
```

Now the logic of my code in `PageTwo` assumes that the user entered it in Portrait Mode. However in reality that will not always be true because the user could enter `pageTwo` while in LandscapeMode. In that case the controls dont readjust to landscape mode as the method of reorientation does not get called in pageTwo. My question is how can I call the reorientation method `viewWillTransitionToSize` manually and pass a size parameter in which the size width is greater than the height ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whatever you're doing in `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, you should probably do in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead. Those are sent both on a rotation **and** when the view controller's view first comes onto the screen, and UIKit updates the view's frame before calling `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: ill give this a try and report back

Comment: @MistyD that report back is taking a while.

Comment: Helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Rob, If i use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, wouldn't it unnecessarily keep doing whatever i need done only on rotation all the time?

Comment: What do you mean by “all the time”? That message is only sent when the view controller’s view needs layout, which might not be not very often.

Comment: @robmayoff - I have two view controller , In one updating the frame at **viewWillTransitionToSize**  does the job for me and in another updating the frame at **viewDidLayoutSubviews** does the job for me.It's very strange

Comment: Feel free to [visit the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911924/8910363) and leave your comments

Comment: only `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` are being called several times for a single rotation