# iOS part of viewcontroller goes black when orientation changes

Tags: ios, uitableview, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

When I change viewcontroller orientation while it's loading on particular orientation, part of the screen goes blank at the bottom.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Have tableview(Not necessary I think. could be any view) in a view controller
2. Push a new viewcontroller which also has a tableview(Not necessary I think. could be any view)  during
   an action
3. Rotate the screen from one orientation to Another(Portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait).now you will be able to see the dark part.
4. Press back button to pop the current viewcontroller
5. Now rotate from one orientation to Another(Portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait).now you will be able to see the dark part here as well.

The bottom part of viewcontroller goes black.

I am able to reproduce 7 out of 10 times.

**FYI:**

My Viewcontroller has only tableview that's all and all cells has autolayout constraints. 
Trying to understand why it happened and I would like to fix it.

**More details on reproducing the issue:**

Basically you can reproduce this issue only if you hold your device in slanting position and either push or pop a view controller and while the page is trying to load , you have to change the orientation then the issue happens.

(Pun intended.... lol )
In other words ,you have to tilt you device as if you are steering the wheel :).

This issue can only happen if you use your device like a steering wheel :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIView frame not updating after orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262481/uiview-frame-not-updating-after-orientation-change)

Comment: I'm just using tableview in the viewcontroller and no other elecement and each tableview cell has autolayout contraints ... so no need for updating the frame on my own. I'm still thinking what else could cause this

Comment: Consider adding the screenshot

Comment: can you share some code for this `UIViewController`?

Comment: show the constraints of your tableview

Comment: @ParthBhuva - the constraints have been set up properly there is no issue. It seems the dark color is coming as there is an issue to draw for tableview to new the orientation.  that's the reason it's not happening consistently.

Comment: show your two class code and add OP UI.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma - My viewcontroller has a only one view that is tableview and all I'm doing is loading the some local data into the tableview. tableview uses autolayout constraints to spread to the whole screen of viewcontroller. There are no autolayout issues either for tableview or tableviewcell. This issue happens only in the above mentioned scenario

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - what's OP UI ? both the classes are viewcontrollers just with one tableview for the complete screen. Both uses local data to show data elements in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one view controller(Parent the one that pushes new view controller) setting the frame at **viewDidLayoutSubviews** solves the issue in another view controller(The child view controller , one that's getting pushed) setting the frame at **viewWillTransition** fixes the problem :) But still I don't know why there's no universal solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced the same issue.

My view controller had just one tableview and when we tilt , I mean change the orientation during a navigational push or pop this used to happen.

Try setting the frame
 in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
   -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    // To check if there's any mismatch between the sizes of screen and tableview then set the tableview frame same as screen frame.
    if (CGRectGetHeight(frame) != height && CGRectGetWidth(frame) != width) {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

or try setting the frame in `viewWillTransitionToSize`

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(screen);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screen);
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    if (CGRectGetHeight(frame) != height && CGRectGetWidth(frame) != width) {
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

FYI:

if setting the frame `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);` doesn't work then you could try `[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded]`

Comment: It's working in one of my view controller and it's not working in other view controller

Comment: It's strange. Can you put some NSLogs in the code segment for both tableview and screen's width and height over there and see what's happening ?

Comment: I tried putting the logs around the area. Here is what I found neither **viewDidLayoutSubviews** nor **viewWillLayoutSubviews** is getting called when this issue happens in this particular viewcontroller. I had the same part of the page dark issue in some  other view controller. There the problem got solved by using the above code snippet and there the the layoutsubviews were getting called that's the reason the issue got fixed.I'm wondering why those delegates are not getting called for this particular view controller?

Comment: Try calling **viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator** and set the frame

Answer (score 3):

In your viewWillTransition method call layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: try this in viewWillTransition call setNeedsLayout() and then call layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Setting the table frame fixes the issue in one view controller ( viewWillTransition) thanks  , whereas in another viewcontroller it's not working. strange. By the way setNeedsLayout is asynchronous and view has to wait for next UI update cycle whereas layoutifneeded is synchronous.  both are not working anyway

Answer (score 3):

Try to reset the layout of TableView after rotation by using this method,

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

or

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: It's not getting called when the problem happens

Comment: ok, which ViewController do you want to allow to get rotated?

Comment: there is no problem with viewcontroller rotation , it rotates but sometimes , the bottom of the page is dark during the orientational change, please look at the steps to reproduce. My problem is Neither viewDidLayoutSubviews nor viewWillLayoutSubviews getting called when this problem happens.

Answer (score 2):

Set frame again in

> viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: when I'm using auto-layout why do I have to worry about frame's ?

Comment: @dineshR In this, you get frame size before the transition. So your view is not updating. You need to get the frame size after the transition has been completed. You can use this method also "viewWillTransition" for that.

Comment: Instead of setting the frame , May I activate the autolayout to redraw ?

Comment: @dineshR If autolayout to redraw works then it's good otherwise we have this option.

Comment: you can invoke **layoutIfNeeded** and see if that helps

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H it's not working every time.. in fact, it's not working in my case

Comment: Try setting the View's frame again

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews is not getting called when the problem happens